# In laravel project i am trying to get data from mysql database table " categories" all fields returned except one "title"

Tags: laravel

The following migration code:

> 

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('categories')){
            Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title', 191)->nullable();
                $table->string('icon', 191)->nullable();
                $table->string('slug', 191)->nullable();
                $table->enum('featured', array('1','0'));
                $table->enum('status', array('1','0'));
                $table->integer('position')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }

}
```

Route:

> /* Test routes*/

```
Route::get('allcat',function (){
    return $category = App\Categories::all();
});
```

Result:

```
[
{
id: 1,
title: "",
icon: "icon",
slug: "slug",
featured: "1",
status: "1",
position: 1,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
},
{
id: 2,
title: "",
icon: "icon",
slug: "slug",
featured: "1",
status: "1",
position: 1,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
},
{
id: 3,
title: "",
icon: "iconCat1",
slug: null,
featured: "1",
status: "1",
position: null,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
}
]
```

Comment: its returning blank strings, is there actually something in those `title` fields?

Comment: Have you checked the `title` field data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking your Model to check that the attributes are fillable e.g.

```
/**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
         'title', 'icon', 'slug',  'featured', 'status', 'position'
    ];
```